# Sum values from different dictionaries based on "temporal instant"

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, such as:
For each key (A1 and A2) I have a list of items bought in a different place (T1 and T2) with the amount spent by the temporal time. **example: Person A1 spend 3.0 at timestep 1, at supermarket T1.**

```
{'A1': {'T1': [1, 3.0, 3, 4.0], 'T2': [2, 2.0]}, 'A2': {'T1': [1, 0.0, 3, 5.0], 'T2': [2, 3.0]}}
```

What I want to do is sum each sub dictionary, to obtain the total spent at each timestep in each supermarket:

```
A1 A2  A1 A2  A1 A2
T1+T1  T2+T2  T1+T1 (The lists are followed by: timestep + money spent)
 [3.0, 5.0, 9.0] <<<< output
   1    2    3
res 3.0 + 0.0 = 3.0  and 2.0 + 3.0 = 5.0 and  5.0 + 4.0 = 9.0
```

How can I do this? I've tried a for, but I've created a big mess

Output:

```
[3.0, 5.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: post expected result

Comment: Since you are adding up time stamped values together, I would create a 2d lists like this: [[3.0, 0.0], [2.0, 3.0], [5.0, 4.0]], then add up the timestamped values in the list.

Comment: @SportsCodes it shoud by `[3.0, 6.0, 9.0]`?

Comment: the timestamps are in the list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution for your problem, but I would suggest you use dict for time stamped value to distinguish between timestamp and value.

Instead of this:

`{"A1": {"T1": [1, 3.0, 3, 4.0]}}`

Do this:
`{"A1": {"T1": {1: 3.0, 3: 4.0}}}`

```
import json

dict = json.loads('{"A1": {"T1": [1, 3.0, 3, 4.0], "T2": [2, 2.0]}, "A2": {"T1": [1, 0.0, 3, 5.0], "T2": [2, 3.0]}}')

result = {}
for person, supermarket in dict.items():
   for _, timestamped_values in supermarket.items():
      for i in range(len(timestamped_values)):
         if i % 2 == 0 and i < len(timestamped_values)-1:
            result.setdefault(timestamped_values[i], []).append(timestamped_values[i+1])

print(result)
```

Result is:

```
{1: [3.0, 0.0], 3: [4.0, 5.0], 2: [2.0, 3.0]}
```

Just add up the values in the list to get your result. I will keep it this way just in case you need to do other operations on the timestamped values.